# Channel Form and Permissions

Tags: safecracker

I'm running a site with EE 2.11.9.  I have a channel form that allows our members to update the title, description, etc. of the entry  However, they can't edit the categories unless they belong to a Membership Group 1.

If a user belongs to Membership Group 1, then everything works fine. 
 However, if they belong to Membership Group 2, then the categories are erased when they hit Submit to save the form.

Here is my code:

```
{if member_group == '1' }
<select name="category[]" id="categories" size="8" multiple="multiple">
    {categories show_group="12"}
        <option value="{category_id}"{selected}>{category_name}</option>
    {/categories}
</select>
{/if}
```

If I remove that part from the Channel form, then everything works fine (except admins can't edit the categories).

Any suggestions on how to save the current categories if you aren't an admin?

Comment: Is member_group 1 the same as "Membership Group A"?

Comment: Yes - I just edited the original post to make them the same.

Comment: It is annoying, but it is actually how the Channel API works; every time you save an entry, you *must* submit every piece of data, and any missing data is NULL and converted to an empty string: https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/development/api/api_channel_entries.html I once wrecked 100 entries without a backup doing this. Lesson learned; always use dev servers and backups for development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not EE related and maybe wrong. But you can hide (with css) if member_group_id != 1

Comment: I actually thought about doing that if there wasn't a good solution!

Comment: I ended up using CSS with "display:none" if the user wasn't in the proper group.  Might not be the best solution, but in this case it did the trick!